# Extracting text fields from <span> tags in an HTML message

Tags: c#, html, parsing

What i'm doing

I have a string with html information like this:

```
<p> <span class="fieldText" fieldId="field-4">Some text</span> this is a test</p>
```

My goal in the method is to create a dictionary with this value:

```
**key**     **value**
field-4    Some text
```

This is the code that i'm using to accomplish my task:

```
public static Dictionary<int,String> getFields(String mensaje) 
    {
        Dictionary<int,String> fields = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        Match m = Regex.Match(mensaje, @"^(.*?<span .*?>(.*?)</span>.*?)+$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Groups[2].Captures.Count; i++)
        {
            String value = m.Groups[1].Captures[i].Value;
            Match m2 = Regex.Match(value, "^(.*?fieldId=.*?\"(.*?)\">.*?)+$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            String fieldId = m2.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value;
            fieldId = fieldId.Replace("field-", String.Empty);
            fields.Add(int.Parse(fieldId),m.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value);
        }

        return fields;
    }
```

How can i improve my code?

Comment: What about your gold?

Comment: @Steven Jeuris, hi, what do you mean with about change my gold??

Comment: You used the word 'gold' in your question where I think you meant to say 'goal'. Steve is just teasing you a bit =).

Comment: _"My gold in the method it's a dictionary with this value"_, I'm guessing you mean something along the lines of _"My goal is to extract the values into a dictionary as follows:"_, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris thank's for you concern I'm reaylly appreciate

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is *Code Review* not *Rewrite My Code*, however I would suggest using a third-party Html parser (like the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for example) over regular expressions if that's an option.

I realize you're doing very trivial parsing here, but from my personal experiences regular expressions grow to unmaintainable status quicker than anything in software development.

If you were to use a Html parser, you could do something like this:

```
string htmlToParse = "<p><span class=\"fieldText\" fieldId=\"field-4\">Some text</span> this is a test</p><p><span class=\"fieldText\" fieldId=\"field-5\">Some more text</span> this is another test</p>";
const string ElementToParse = "span";
const string IdField = "FieldId";

HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlToParse);

int fieldId = default( int );

Dictionary<int,string> fieldValuesTable = 
(
    from
        htmlNode in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
    where
        htmlNode.Name.Equals( ElementToParse, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase )
        &&
        htmlNode.Attributes.Contains( IdField )
    let
        id = htmlNode.Attributes[ IdField ].Value
    where
        Int32.TryParse( id.Substring( id.IndexOf( "-" ) + 1 ), out fieldId ) // this is stil not ideal,
    select
        new { Id = fieldId, Text = htmlNode.InnerText }
).ToDictionary( f => f.Id, f => f.Text );
```

You get the output:

```
4 : Some text
5 : Some more text
```

IMHO, it's much cleaner and maintainable.